# Adding table view dynamically in QT

Tags: qt, dynamic, widget, tableview

How to add multiple table views dynamically in QT? The table views should not overlap with each other/other widgets in the screen

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the Qt documentation and examples, for example the [Basic Layouts Example.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/layouts-basiclayouts.html)

Answer (score 1):

For creating tableviews dynamically

```
QTableView *t1=new QTableView(this);
QTableView *t2=new QTableView(this);
```

For handling overlapping issue with each other

```
t1->setGeometry(x_pos,y_pos,width1,height1);
t2->setGeometry(x_pos+t1->geometry().width(),y_pos,width2,height2);
t1->show();
t2->show();
```

You have to keep track of positions of other widgets and set geometry accordingly.